# MVC DoSomething() without redirecting

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC, and want to know how can I run code on controller without redirecting to another page.

My View:

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("DoSomething", "MyController",  new {  })">
```

My Controller:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
   ...
}
```

clicking it does run the code but it then redirects me to a blank view. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the action via an AJAX request.  Something like this:

```
<a id="doSomething" href="#">click here</a>
```

And in the JavaScript code (using jQuery, since it should be available in your MVC project by default):

```
$('#doSomething').click(function () {
    $.get('@Url.Action("DoSomething", "MyController",  new {  })', function(response) {
        // do something with the response?
    });
    return false;
});
```

This will make an asynchronous call from the page to your action.  The response from the action will be in the `response` value of the callback function in the JavaScript.

**Edit:** Given that this link isn't *actually* a link, it's also recommended that it isn't an anchor tag in the first place.  This tag, combined with the above JavaScript code, should result in the same functionality:

```
<span id="doSomething">click here</span>
```

You can style it to behave like a link in the CSS:

```
#doSomething {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Or however your CSS behaves with links.

Comment: -1: one should **NEVER** write `href="javascript:void(0);"`. Ever. Also, nobody mentioned jQuery. You might not be aware of it (seeing how you have only ~40k point and all), but jQuery is NOT synonymous to JavaScript.

Comment: @tereško: Curious, what should go in the anchor tag instead?  I guess I've never experienced a downside to that so I've never searched for alternatives.  What's the downside?  As for jQuery, he's clearly using ASP.NET MVC which comes with jQuery bundled.  No need to be rude about it.

Comment: @tereško: Either way, the answer has been updated with additional information.

Comment: The `HREF` attribute should contain a proper link (if you even need a link), that would provide same functionality if JS for some reason failed or was disabled. If the tag really *needs* to be a link and you want to attach a functionality to it, you can circumvent the default behaviour using `event.preventDefault()` (and the IE's alternative) .. FYI, it works with all sorts of JS events, not just clicks.

Comment: +1000 for tereško. The `javascript: void(0);` thing is a holdover from the bad old days. One downside, if you really need a reason to type less code that does nothing, is that screen readers will read that out as if it were the hyperlink's destination.